# How can I set counter with start/end number value in FlipClock.js

Tags: javascript, counter, flipclock

I have set counter with a start/end number but when I give to 27 number for start then it starts from 17,28,29 but it should start like 28,29.

Link: https://codepen.io/dokulac-emailure/pen/RwbrEEb

We need to remove 17 number and keep only 28,29 number: http://prntscr.com/osftw9

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock,countup;

    $(document).ready(function() {


        // Instantiate a counter
        clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 27, {
            clockFace: 'Counter',
            autoStart: true,
        });


        countup = setInterval(function() { 
         if(clock.getTime().time > 28) {
           clock.stop();
           clearInterval(countup);
         }
        },500); 


    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should post that on the developer's forum. Also I would expect you to use the onInterval callback after reading the documentation

Comment: Okay, Thanks @mplungjan. Let me try

Comment: I guess, this is the problem with library.

Comment: Yeah, Right @Rohit.007. But I need to fix it on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlipClock` is having more issues, even it does not supports the callback given in its own website. below is the work around to solve the problem.

It animates both of the side from previous values so for 28 it starts by digits, 2 from 1 and 8 from 7, so initial value seems 17

Just added more conditions of opacity (hide/show won't work) to hide and show the element and added start and end condition.

```js
var FlipClock,Base=function(){};Base.extend=function(t,i){"use strict";var e=Base.prototype.extend;Base._prototyping=!0;var s=new this;e.call(s,t),s.base=function(){},delete Base._prototyping;var n=s.constructor,o=s.constructor=function(){if(!Base._prototyping)if(this._constructing||this.constructor==o)this._constructing=!0,n.apply(this,arguments),delete this._constructing;else if(null!==arguments[0])return(arguments[0].extend||e).call(arguments[0],s)};return o.ancestor=this,o.extend=this.extend,o.forEach=this.forEach,o.implement=this.implement,o.prototype=s,o.toString=this.toString,o.valueOf=function(t){return"object"==t?o:n.valueOf()},e.call(o,i),"function"==typeof o.init&&o.init(),o},Base.prototype={extend:function(t,i){if(arguments.length>1){var e=this[t];if(e&&"function"==typeof i&&(!e.valueOf||e.valueOf()!=i.valueOf())&&/\bbase\b/.test(i)){var s=i.valueOf();(i=function(){var t=this.base||Base.prototype.base;this.base=e;var i=s.apply(this,arguments);return this.base=t,i}).valueOf=function(t){return"object"==t?i:s},i.toString=Base.toString}this[t]=i}else if(t){var n=Base.prototype.extend;Base._prototyping||"function"==typeof this||(n=this.extend||n);for(var o={toSource:null},r=["constructor","toString","valueOf"],a=Base._prototyping?0:1;c=r[a++];)t[c]!=o[c]&&n.call(this,c,t[c]);for(var c in t)o[c]||n.call(this,c,t[c])}return this}},Base=Base.extend({constructor:function(){this.extend(arguments[0])}},{ancestor:Object,version:"1.1",forEach:function(t,i,e){for(var s in t)void 0===this.prototype[s]&&i.call(e,t[s],s,t)},implement:function(){for(var t=0;t<arguments.length;t++)"function"==typeof arguments[t]?arguments[t](this.prototype):this.prototype.extend(arguments[t]);return this},toString:function(){return String(this.valueOf())}}),function(t){"use strict";(FlipClock=function(t,i,e){return new FlipClock.Factory(t,i,e)}).Lang={},FlipClock.Base=Base.extend({buildDate:"2013-11-07",version:"0.3.1",constructor:function(i,e){"object"!=typeof i&&(i={}),"object"!=typeof e&&(e={}),this.setOptions(t.extend(!0,{},i,e))},callback:function(t){if("function"==typeof t){for(var i=[],e=1;e<=arguments.length;e++)arguments[e]&&i.push(arguments[e]);t.apply(this,i)}},log:function(t){window.console&&console.log&&console.log(t)},getOption:function(t){return!!this[t]&&this[t]},getOptions:function(){return this},setOption:function(t,i){this[t]=i},setOptions:function(t){for(var i in t)void 0!==t[i]&&this.setOption(i,t[i])}}),FlipClock.Factory=FlipClock.Base.extend({autoStart:!0,callbacks:{destroy:!1,create:!1,init:!1,interval:!1,start:!1,stop:!1,reset:!1},classes:{active:"flip-clock-active",before:"flip-clock-before",divider:"flip-clock-divider",dot:"flip-clock-dot",label:"flip-clock-label",flip:"flip",play:"play",wrapper:"flip-clock-wrapper"},clockFace:"HourlyCounter",defaultClockFace:"HourlyCounter",defaultLanguage:"english",language:"english",lang:!1,face:!0,running:!1,time:!1,timer:!1,lists:[],$wrapper:!1,constructor:function(i,e,s){this.lists=[],this.running=!1,this.base(s),this.$wrapper=t(i).addClass(this.classes.wrapper),this.time=new FlipClock.Time(this,e?Math.round(e):0),this.timer=new FlipClock.Timer(this,s),this.lang=this.loadLanguage(this.language),this.face=this.loadClockFace(this.clockFace,s),this.autoStart&&this.start()},loadClockFace:function(t,i){var e;return t=t.ucfirst()+"Face",(e=FlipClock[t]?new FlipClock[t](this,i):new FlipClock[this.defaultClockFace+"Face"](this,i)).build(),e},loadLanguage:function(t){return FlipClock.Lang[t.ucfirst()]?FlipClock.Lang[t.ucfirst()]:FlipClock.Lang[t]?FlipClock.Lang[t]:FlipClock.Lang[this.defaultLanguage]},localize:function(t,i){var e=this.lang;if(!t)return null;var s=t.toLowerCase();return"object"==typeof i&&(e=i),e&&e[s]?e[s]:t},start:function(t){var i=this;i.running||i.countdown&&!(i.countdown&&i.time.time>0)?i.log("Trying to start timer when countdown already at 0"):(i.face.start(i.time),i.timer.start(function(){i.flip(),"function"==typeof t&&t()}))},stop:function(t){for(var i in this.face.stop(),this.timer.stop(t),this.lists)this.lists[i].stop()},reset:function(t){this.timer.reset(t),this.face.reset()},setTime:function(t){this.time.time=t,this.face.setTime(t)},getTime:function(t){return this.time},setCountdown:function(t){var i=this.running;this.countdown=!!t,i&&(this.stop(),this.start())},flip:function(){this.face.flip()}}),FlipClock.Face=FlipClock.Base.extend({dividers:[],factory:!1,lists:[],constructor:function(t,i){this.base(i),this.factory=t,this.dividers=[]},build:function(){},createDivider:function(i,e,s){"boolean"!=typeof e&&e||(s=e,e=i);var n=['<span class="'+this.factory.classes.dot+' top"></span>','<span class="'+this.factory.classes.dot+' bottom"></span>'].join("");s&&(n=""),i=this.factory.localize(i);var o=['<span class="'+this.factory.classes.divider+" "+(e||"").toLowerCase()+'">','<span class="'+this.factory.classes.label+'">'+(i||"")+"</span>",n,"</span>"];return t(o.join(""))},createList:function(t,i){return"object"==typeof t&&(i=t,t=0),new FlipClock.List(this.factory,t,i)},reset:function(){},setTime:function(t){this.flip(t)},addDigit:function(t){var i=this.createList(t,{classes:{active:this.factory.classes.active,before:this.factory.classes.before,flip:this.factory.classes.flip}});i.$obj.insertBefore(this.factory.lists[0].$obj),this.factory.lists.unshift(i)},start:function(){},stop:function(){},flip:function(i,e){var s=this;e||(s.factory.countdown?(s.factory.time.time<=0&&s.factory.stop(),s.factory.time.time--):s.factory.time.time++);var n=s.factory.lists.length-i.length;n<0&&(n=0);t.each(i,function(t,i){t+=n;var o=s.factory.lists[t];if(o){var r=o.digit;o.select(i),i==r||e||o.play()}else s.addDigit(i),!0});for(var o=0;o<i.length;o++)o>=n&&s.factory.lists[o].digit!=i[o]&&s.factory.lists[o].select(i[o])}}),FlipClock.List=FlipClock.Base.extend({digit:0,classes:{active:"flip-clock-active",before:"flip-clock-before",flip:"flip"},factory:!1,$obj:!1,items:[],constructor:function(t,i,e){this.factory=t,this.digit=i,this.$obj=this.createList(),i>0&&this.select(i),this.factory.$wrapper.append(this.$obj)},select:function(t){void 0===t?t=this.digit:this.digit=t;var i=this.$obj.find('[data-digit="'+t+'"]');this.$obj.find("."+this.classes.active).removeClass(this.classes.active),this.$obj.find("."+this.classes.before).removeClass(this.classes.before);this.factory.countdown?i.is(":last-child")?this.$obj.find(":first-child").addClass(this.classes.before):i.next().addClass(this.classes.before):i.is(":first-child")?this.$obj.find(":last-child").addClass(this.classes.before):i.prev().addClass(this.classes.before),i.addClass(this.classes.active)},play:function(){this.$obj.addClass(this.factory.classes.play)},stop:function(){var t=this;setTimeout(function(){t.$obj.removeClass(t.factory.classes.play)},this.factory.timer.interval)},createList:function(){for(var i=t('<ul class="'+this.classes.flip+" "+(this.factory.running?this.factory.classes.play:"")+'" />'),e=0;e<10;e++){var s=t(['<li data-digit="'+e+'">','<a href="#">','<div class="up">','<div class="shadow"></div>','<div class="inn">'+e+"</div>","</div>",'<div class="down">','<div class="shadow"></div>','<div class="inn">'+e+"</div>","</div>","</a>","</li>"].join(""));this.items.push(s),i.append(s)}return i}}),FlipClock.Time=FlipClock.Base.extend({minimumDigits:0,time:0,factory:!1,constructor:function(t,i,e){this.base(e),this.factory=t,i&&(this.time=i)},convertDigitsToArray:function(t){var i=[];t=t.toString();for(var e=0;e<t.length;e++)t[e].match(/^\d*$/g)&&i.push(t[e]);return i},digit:function(t){var i=this.toString(),e=i.length;return!!i[e-t]&&i[e-t]},digitize:function(i){var e=[];return t.each(i,function(t,i){1==(i=i.toString()).length&&(i="0"+i);for(var s=0;s<i.length;s++)e.push(i[s])}),e.length>this.minimumDigits&&(this.minimumDigits=e.length),this.minimumDigits>e.length&&e.unshift("0"),e},getDayCounter:function(t){var i=[this.getDays(),this.getHours(!0),this.getMinutes(!0)];return t&&i.push(this.getSeconds(!0)),this.digitize(i)},getDays:function(t){var i=this.time/60/60/24;return t&&(i%=7),Math.floor(i)},getHourCounter:function(){return this.digitize([this.getHours(),this.getMinutes(!0),this.getSeconds(!0)])},getHourly:function(){return this.getHourCounter()},getHours:function(t){var i=this.time/60/60;return t&&(i%=24),Math.floor(i)},getMilitaryTime:function(){var t=new Date;return this.digitize([t.getHours(),t.getMinutes(),t.getSeconds()])},getMinutes:function(t){var i=this.time/60;return t&&(i%=60),Math.floor(i)},getMinuteCounter:function(){return this.digitize([this.getMinutes(),this.getSeconds(!0)])},getSeconds:function(t){var i=this.time;return t&&(60==i?i=0:i%=60),Math.ceil(i)},getTime:function(){var t=new Date,i=t.getHours();return this.digitize([i>12?i-12:0===i?12:i,t.getMinutes(),t.getSeconds()])},getWeeks:function(){var t=this.time/60/60/24/7;return mod&&(t%=52),Math.floor(t)},removeLeadingZeros:function(i,e){var s=0,n=[];return t.each(e,function(t,o){t<i?s+=parseInt(e[t],10):n.push(e[t])}),0===s?n:e},toString:function(){return this.time.toString()}}),FlipClock.Timer=FlipClock.Base.extend({callbacks:{destroy:!1,create:!1,init:!1,interval:!1,start:!1,stop:!1,reset:!1},count:0,factory:!1,interval:1e3,constructor:function(t,i){this.base(i),this.factory=t,this.callback(this.callbacks.init),this.callback(this.callbacks.create)},getElapsed:function(){return this.count*this.interval},getElapsedTime:function(){return new Date(this.time+this.getElapsed())},reset:function(t){clearInterval(this.timer),this.count=0,this._setInterval(t),this.callback(this.callbacks.reset)},start:function(t){this.factory.running=!0,this._createTimer(t),this.callback(this.callbacks.start)},stop:function(t){this.factory.running=!1,this._clearInterval(t),this.callback(this.callbacks.stop),this.callback(t)},_clearInterval:function(){clearInterval(this.timer)},_createTimer:function(t){this._setInterval(t)},_destroyTimer:function(t){this._clearInterval(),this.timer=!1,this.callback(t),this.callback(this.callbacks.destroy)},_interval:function(t){this.callback(this.callbacks.interval),this.callback(t),this.count++},_setInterval:function(t){var i=this;i.timer=setInterval(function(){i._interval(t)},this.interval)}}),String.prototype.ucfirst=function(){return this.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+this.substr(1)},t.fn.FlipClock=function(i,e){return"object"==typeof i&&(e=i,i=0),new FlipClock(t(this),i,e)},t.fn.flipClock=function(i,e){return t.fn.FlipClock(i,e)}}(jQuery),function(t){FlipClock.TwentyFourHourClockFace=FlipClock.Face.extend({constructor:function(t,i){t.countdown=!1,this.base(t,i)},build:function(i){var e=this,s=this.factory.$wrapper.find("ul");(i=i||(this.factory.time.time||this.factory.time.getMilitaryTime())).length>s.length&&t.each(i,function(t,i){e.factory.lists.push(e.createList(i))}),this.dividers.push(this.createDivider()),this.dividers.push(this.createDivider()),t(this.dividers[0]).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2].$obj),t(this.dividers[1]).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4].$obj),this._clearExcessDigits(),this.autoStart&&this.start()},flip:function(t){t=t||this.factory.time.getMilitaryTime(),this.base(t)},_clearExcessDigits:function(){for(var t=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2],i=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4],e=6;e<10;e++)t.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove(),i.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove()}})}(jQuery),function(t){FlipClock.CounterFace=FlipClock.Face.extend({autoStart:!1,constructor:function(t,i){t.timer.interval=0,t.autoStart=!1,t.running=!0,t.increment=function(){t.countdown=!1,t.setTime(t.getTime().time+1)},t.decrement=function(){t.countdown=!0,t.setTime(t.getTime().time-1)},t.setValue=function(i){t.setTime(i)},t.setCounter=function(i){t.setTime(i)},this.base(t,i)},build:function(){var i=this,e=this.factory.$wrapper.find("ul"),s=[],n=this.factory.getTime().digitize([this.factory.getTime().time]);n.length>e.length&&t.each(n,function(t,e){var n=i.createList(e);n.select(e),s.push(n)}),t.each(s,function(t,i){i.play()}),this.factory.lists=s},flip:function(t){var i=this.factory.getTime().digitize([this.factory.getTime().time]);this.base(i,t)}})}(jQuery),function(t){FlipClock.DailyCounterFace=FlipClock.Face.extend({showSeconds:!0,constructor:function(t,i){this.base(t,i)},build:function(i,e){var s=this,n=this.factory.$wrapper.find("ul"),o=[],r=0;(e=e||this.factory.time.getDayCounter(this.showSeconds)).length>n.length&&t.each(e,function(t,i){o.push(s.createList(i))}),this.factory.lists=o,this.showSeconds?t(this.createDivider("Seconds")).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2].$obj):r=2,t(this.createDivider("Minutes")).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4+r].$obj),t(this.createDivider("Hours")).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-6+r].$obj),t(this.createDivider("Days",!0)).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[0].$obj),this._clearExcessDigits(),this.autoStart&&this.start()},flip:function(t,i){i||(i=this.factory.time.getDayCounter(this.showSeconds)),this.base(i,t)},_clearExcessDigits:function(){for(var t=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2],i=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4],e=6;e<10;e++)t.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove(),i.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove()}})}(jQuery),function(t){FlipClock.HourlyCounterFace=FlipClock.Face.extend({clearExcessDigits:!0,constructor:function(t,i){this.base(t,i)},build:function(i,e){var s=this,n=this.factory.$wrapper.find("ul"),o=[];(e=e||this.factory.time.getHourCounter()).length>n.length&&t.each(e,function(t,i){o.push(s.createList(i))}),this.factory.lists=o,t(this.createDivider("Seconds")).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2].$obj),t(this.createDivider("Minutes")).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4].$obj),i||t(this.createDivider("Hours",!0)).insertBefore(this.factory.lists[0].$obj),this.clearExcessDigits&&this._clearExcessDigits(),this.autoStart&&this.start()},flip:function(t,i){i||(i=this.factory.time.getHourCounter()),this.base(i,t)},_clearExcessDigits:function(){for(var t=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2],i=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4],e=6;e<10;e++)t.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove(),i.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove()}})}(jQuery),jQuery,FlipClock.MinuteCounterFace=FlipClock.HourlyCounterFace.extend({clearExcessDigits:!1,constructor:function(t,i){this.base(t,i)},build:function(){this.base(!0,this.factory.time.getMinuteCounter())},flip:function(t){this.base(t,this.factory.time.getMinuteCounter())}}),function(t){FlipClock.TwelveHourClockFace=FlipClock.TwentyFourHourClockFace.extend({meridium:!1,meridiumText:"AM",build:function(i){i=i||(this.factory.time.time?this.factory.time.time:this.factory.time.getTime()),this.base(i),this.meridiumText=this._isPM()?"PM":"AM",this.meridium=t(['<ul class="flip-clock-meridium">',"<li>",'<a href="#">'+this.meridiumText+"</a>","</li>","</ul>"].join("")),this.meridium.insertAfter(this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-1].$obj)},flip:function(){this.meridiumText!=this._getMeridium()&&(this.meridiumText=this._getMeridium(),this.meridium.find("a").html(this.meridiumText)),this.base(this.factory.time.getTime())},_getMeridium:function(){return(new Date).getHours()>=12?"PM":"AM"},_isPM:function(){return"PM"==this._getMeridium()},_clearExcessDigits:function(){for(var t=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-2],i=this.factory.lists[this.factory.lists.length-4],e=6;e<10;e++)t.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove(),i.$obj.find("li:last-child").remove()}})}(jQuery),jQuery,FlipClock.Lang.German={years:"Jahre",months:"Monate",days:"Tage",hours:"Stunden",minutes:"Minuten",seconds:"Sekunden"},FlipClock.Lang.de=FlipClock.Lang.German,FlipClock.Lang["de-de"]=FlipClock.Lang.German,FlipClock.Lang.german=FlipClock.Lang.German,jQuery,FlipClock.Lang.English={years:"Years",months:"Months",days:"Days",hours:"Hours",minutes:"Minutes",seconds:"Seconds"},FlipClock.Lang.en=FlipClock.Lang.English,FlipClock.Lang["en-us"]=FlipClock.Lang.English,FlipClock.Lang.english=FlipClock.Lang.English,jQuery,FlipClock.Lang.Spanish={years:"A&#241;os",months:"Meses",days:"D&#205;as",hours:"Horas",minutes:"Minutos",seconds:"Segundo"},FlipClock.Lang.es=FlipClock.Lang.Spanish,FlipClock.Lang["es-es"]=FlipClock.Lang.Spanish,FlipClock.Lang.spanish=FlipClock.Lang.Spanish,jQuery,FlipClock.Lang.French={years:"ans",months:"mois",days:"jours",hours:"heures",minutes:"minutes",seconds:"secondes"},FlipClock.Lang.fr=FlipClock.Lang.French,FlipClock.Lang["fr-ca"]=FlipClock.Lang.French,FlipClock.Lang.french=FlipClock.Lang.French;
```

```css
.flip-clock-wrapper a{cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;color:#ccc}.flip-clock-wrapper a:hover{color:#fff}.flip-clock-wrapper ul{list-style:none}.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after,.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:before{content:" ";display:table}.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after{clear:both}.flip-clock-wrapper{font:normal 11px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;-webkit-user-select:none}.flip-clock-meridium{background:0 0!important;box-shadow:0 0 0!important}.flip-clock-meridium a{color:#313333}.flip-clock-wrapper{text-align:center;position:relative;width:100%;margin:1em}.flip-clock-wrapper:after,.flip-clock-wrapper:before{content:" ";display:table}.flip-clock-wrapper:after{clear:both}.flip-clock-wrapper ul{position:relative;float:left;margin:10px;width:70px;height:135px;font-weight:700;line-height:87px;border-radius:6px;background:#000}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li{z-index:1;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;line-height:87px;text-decoration:none!important}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li:first-child{z-index:2}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a{display:block;height:100%;-webkit-perspective:200px;-moz-perspective:200px;perspective:200px;margin:0!important;overflow:visible!important;cursor:default!important}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div{z-index:1;position:absolute;left:0;width:100%;height:50%;font-size:80px;overflow:hidden;outline:1px solid transparent}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div .shadow{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:2}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up{-webkit-transform-origin:50% 100%;-moz-transform-origin:50% 100%;-ms-transform-origin:50% 100%;-o-transform-origin:50% 100%;transform-origin:50% 100%;top:0}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after{content:"";position:absolute;top:65px;left:0;z-index:5;width:100%;height:3px;background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4)}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down{-webkit-transform-origin:50% 0;-moz-transform-origin:50% 0;-ms-transform-origin:50% 0;-o-transform-origin:50% 0;transform-origin:50% 0;bottom:0;border-bottom-left-radius:6px;border-bottom-right-radius:6px}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn{position:absolute;left:0;z-index:1;width:100%;height:200%;color:#ccc;text-shadow:0 1px 2px #000;text-align:center;line-height:130px;background-color:#333;border-radius:6px;font-size:120px}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up div.inn{top:0}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down div.inn{bottom:0}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before{z-index:3}.flip-clock-wrapper .flip{box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.7)}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active{-webkit-animation:asd .5s .5s linear both;-moz-animation:asd .5s .5s linear both;animation:asd .5s .5s linear both;z-index:5}.flip-clock-divider{float:left;display:inline-block;position:relative;width:20px;height:100px}.flip-clock-divider:first-child{width:0}.flip-clock-dot{display:block;background:#323434;width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;border-radius:50%;box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);left:5px}.flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label{position:absolute;top:-1.5em;right:-86px;color:#000;text-shadow:none}.flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label{right:-88px}.flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label{right:-91px}.flip-clock-dot.top{top:30px}.flip-clock-dot.bottom{bottom:30px}@-webkit-keyframes asd{0%{z-index:2}20%{z-index:4}100%{z-index:4}}@-moz-keyframes asd{0%{z-index:2}20%{z-index:4}100%{z-index:4}}@-o-keyframes asd{0%{z-index:2}20%{z-index:4}100%{z-index:4}}@keyframes asd{0%{z-index:2}20%{z-index:4}100%{z-index:4}}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down{z-index:2;-webkit-animation:turn .5s .5s linear both;-moz-animation:turn .5s .5s linear both;animation:turn .5s .5s linear both}@-webkit-keyframes turn{0%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(0)}}@-moz-keyframes turn{0%{-moz-transform:rotateX(90deg)}100%{-moz-transform:rotateX(0)}}@-o-keyframes turn{0%{-o-transform:rotateX(90deg)}100%{-o-transform:rotateX(0)}}@keyframes turn{0%{transform:rotateX(90deg)}100%{transform:rotateX(0)}}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up{z-index:2;-webkit-animation:turn2 .5s linear both;-moz-animation:turn2 .5s linear both;animation:turn2 .5s linear both}@-webkit-keyframes turn2{0%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@-moz-keyframes turn2{0%{-moz-transform:rotateX(0)}100%{-moz-transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@-o-keyframes turn2{0%{-o-transform:rotateX(0)}100%{-o-transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes turn2{0%{transform:rotateX(0)}100%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}.flip-clock-wrapper ul li.flip-clock-active{z-index:3}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up .shadow{background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%);background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,rgba(0,0,0,.1)),color-stop(100%,#000));background:linear,top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%;background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%);background:linear,to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%;-webkit-animation:show .5s linear both;-moz-animation:show .5s linear both;animation:show .5s linear both}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .up .shadow{background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%);background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,rgba(0,0,0,.1)),color-stop(100%,#000));background:linear,top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%;background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%);background:linear,to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,#000 100%;-webkit-animation:hide .5s .3s linear both;-moz-animation:hide .5s .3s linear both;animation:hide .5s .3s linear both}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .down .shadow{background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%);background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#000),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.1)));background:linear,top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%;background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%);background:linear,to bottom,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%;-webkit-animation:show .5s linear both;-moz-animation:show .5s linear both;animation:show .5s linear both}.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down .shadow{background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%);background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#000),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.1)));background:linear,top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%;background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%);background:linear,to bottom,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 100%;-webkit-animation:hide .5s .3s linear both;-moz-animation:hide .5s .3s linear both;animation:hide .5s .2s linear both}@-webkit-keyframes show{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@-moz-keyframes show{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@-o-keyframes show{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@keyframes show{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes hide{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}@-moz-keyframes hide{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}@-o-keyframes hide{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}@keyframes hide{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Countdown Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <html>

    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/js/flipclock/flipclock.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var clock, countup;
            var start = 27, end = 29;
            $('.clock').css('opacity',0);
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Instantiate a counter
                clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), start, {
                    clockFace: 'Counter',
                    autoStart: true
                });

                countup = setInterval(function () {
                    if (clock.getTime().time >= end) {
                        clock.stop();
                        clearInterval(countup);
                    }else{
                        clock.increment();
                        if(clock.getTime().time > start){
                            $('.clock').css('opacity',1);
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>

</body>

</html>
```